# Certbot ssl certificate renewal successful on my nginx server but the validity period of the certificate does not change in web browser

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, vps

I have updated my vps nginx server ssl certificate using the command `sudo certbot certonly --manual --preferred-challenges=dns --email sujith@website.com --server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory --agree-tos -d *.website.com` and verified it in noip. I recieved a success message that tells me the ssl certificate has been updated successfully but when I open the website and inspect the validity period of the certificate in the certificate viewer, it remains unchanged.

I tried reassigning another certificate and got the message "Certificate not yet due for renewal You have an existing certificate that has exactly the same domains or certificate name you requested and isn't close to expiry" How ever, on inspecting the validity period, I noticed it is still unchanged and it is 3 days to the expiry date. Please what do I do? I have restarted the server many times but the problem is still there.